# how to switch my VM from shield mode to normal mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, serial-port, google-compute-engine

After reset a VM integrity, this one is running into shield mode.

I cannot connect in SSH on this VM without going through the serial port.

The VM is in shield mode and nothing is working. How can I switch back to a normal mode to connect to the traditional ports of the VM?

I used this to update un integritry baseline

https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/integrity-monitoring#updating-baseline

Comment: At this point, my advice to you is to create a new instance, attach the failed instance's boot disk to the new instance and copy over your data.

Comment: Why are you sure that it's the shielded / integrity factor?

Could you SSH in before the integrity update? If you SSH in via serial - did the update turn on any firewalls, etc? VPC Firewalls?

Comment: [This](https://cloud.google.com/compute/shielded-vm/docs/modifying-shielded-vm#modify-shielded-vm-instance) should help you to try disabling the shield. Otherwise, just [create snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) of existing VM and build another VM from the snapshot or you can try to [create similar VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-similar-instance) and try to SSH.